# Two Fragments, two different layouts, one activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

i have one activity, which runs fragment A at start in a RelativeLayout,

after that, inside this fragment, i try to open another fragment B, which is somehow an overlay only, it runs in another RelativeLayout, to look above fragment A, so far, all is working good, but the problem is in the onBackPressed():

I open the overlay fragment B, then i press back button, but it closes fragment A only.

Here is my activity's xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_replacement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#0000"
    android:id="@+id/overlay_fragment_replacement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I think this should explain it, but i'm up to provide any additional info.

Comment: Add the complete java code of fragments as well as that activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding Fragments, you can add them to your backstack.

```
getSupportManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Then you can simply check **how many** fragment are in your backstack and remove e.g. Fragment B when **2** when the backstack contains two fragments.

Comment: the second fragment can't always be my fragment B, as i can open fragment C instead, and it'll still be the 2nd fragment in the stack after fragment A, but if i join your answer with what +Petros Masoyan said, with the tag, it can be done, thank you both so much ^_^

Comment: the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) might help you. You can also add strings, but at the end it's just a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags. Before opening fragment B, set the tag equal to for example "a".
Override the onBackPressed() method and check the value of the tag. If it equal to "a" then open the fragment a. If it equal to "b" then open fragment b.

Answer (score 0):

In the [android documentation for Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) it mentions this process.

> If you don't call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment, then that fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it. Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is stopped and is later resumed if the user navigates back.